# MySQL syntax Error on create table query

Tags: mysql, database, phpmyadmin

im creating tables in mySql through phpmyadmin as soon as i run this query

```
CREATE TABLE `teacher` (
  'id' int(11) NOT NULL,
  'name' varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  'gender' ENUM('F','M') NOT NULL,
  'department' varchar(32) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  FOREIGN KEY ('department') REFERENCES     
  departments('name')
  );

#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; 
check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server 
version for the right syntax to use near
 ''id' int(11) NOT NULL, 'name' varchar(45) NOT NULL, 'gender' ENUM('F','M') N' 
at line 2
```

this error shows up

Comment: Backticks and inverted commas are different things

Comment: how stupid of me
thankyou mate <3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
CREATE TABLE teacher (
id int(11) NOT NULL, 
name varchar(45) NOT NULL, 
gender ENUM('F', 'M') NOT NULL,
department varchar(32) NOT NULL, 
PRIMARY KEY (id),
FOREIGN KEY (department) REFERENCES departments(name) 
);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
CREATE TABLE teacher (
id int(11) NOT NULL,
name varchar(45) NOT NULL,
gender ENUM('F','M') NOT NULL,
department  varchar(32) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (id),
FOREIGN KEY (department) REFERENCES     
departments(name)
);
```

for more [Click](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_create_table.asp)